# How to select every YEAR between two year in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How can I select all of the dates between two dates?

My table like this :

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_modification` ( 
      `id_product_modification` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      `id_category` int(11) NOT NULL, 
      `id_sub_category` int(11) NOT NULL, 
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
      `start_production_year` int(8) DEFAULT NULL, 
      `end_production_year` int(8) DEFAULT NULL, 
      `id_product_type` int(8) NOT NULL, 
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_product_modification`) 
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

    INSERT INTO `product_modification` (`id_product_modification`, `id_category`, `id_sub_category`, `name`, `start_production_year`, `end_production_year`, `id_product_type`) VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, 'product_1', 2003, 2006, 1), 
    (2, 1, 1, 'product_2', 2009, 2011, 1), 
    (3, 1, 1, 'product_3', 2014, 2016, 1);
```

I want to display a row like this :

```
id_product_modification |  YEAR
------------------------------------------
                   1    |  2003
                   1    |  2004
                   1    |  2005
                   1    |  2006
                   2    |  2009
                   2    |  2010
                   2    |  2011
                   3    |  2014
                   3    |  2015
                   3    |  2016
```

Is there a built in function for this? Is there a way for a function to return multiple rows?

It has to be a function because I need to use it within other SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Stored procedure and a Cursor

For each row in your table take the start_production_year, end_production_year, and id_product_modification
Assign your start_production_year to a temporal variable and open a loop.
In each loop, increment your temporal variable by one year, then insert the resulting year and id_product_modification into your resulting table
Stop the loop once your temporal variable reaches end_production_year. After your cursor closes, return the table

Edit: Just noticed you asked for a function. I'm pretty much sure functions can't return tables on MySQL

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in-function for this, but you can use the following. It will work for ranges of 100 years, if you need more, you have to add another join inside `IntBase` to make it y3k-ready.

```
select pm.id_product_modification, YearBase.yyyy 
from product_modification pm
join (
 select n + (select min(start_production_year) from product_modification) as yyyy
 from
 ( 
  SELECT INTPART1.n + INTPART2.n * 10 as n
  FROM  
  (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
   union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) INTPART1
   cross join  
  (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
   union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) INTPART2
  ) as IntBase
) as YearBase
on YearBase.yyyy >= pm.start_production_year and YearBase.yyyy <= pm.end_production_year;
```